# Problem - Getting all href from beautifulsoup content

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get **all the href links** from the code below but getting just the first href. Couldnt solve where I am wrong. Can you please help me with this?

```
for i in range(1,3): 
    url = "https://www.gittigidiyor.com/samsung-cep-telefonu?sf=" + str(i)
    r = requests.get(url) 
    source = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
    liste = source.find_all('div', attrs={"class":"gg-w-24 gg-d-24 gg-t-24 gg-m-24 root-column padding-none"}) 
    for url in liste:
        url_phone = "https:" + url.a.get("href")

        print(url_phone)
```

Comment: check the response status code to see if you are getting the expected result with `print(r.status_code)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `find_all('a')` and iterate through those, as opposed to using just `find('a')` or `.a` as it'll only grab the first `<a>` tag it finds.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

for i in range(1,3): 
    url = "https://www.gittigidiyor.com/samsung-cep-telefonu?sf=" + str(i)
    r = requests.get(url) 
    source = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
    liste = source.find_all('div', attrs={"class":"gg-w-24 gg-d-24 gg-t-24 gg-m-24 root-column padding-none"}) 
    for url in liste:
        all_hrefs = url.find_all('a', href=True)
        for href in all_hrefs:
            url_phone = "https:" + href['href']
            print(url_phone)
```